My solution to the fourier transform of multi-dimensional wave equation
Our definition of Fourier transform:$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) e^{-i x \cdot \xi} d x$ 
now consider the wave operator
$$
\square:=-\partial_t^2+\partial_{x^1}^2+\cdots+\partial_{x^d}^2=-\partial_t^2+\Delta
$$
the wave equation is
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\square \phi & =F, \\
\left(\phi, \partial_t \phi\right) \mid\{t=0\} & =\left(\phi_0, \phi_1\right)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
apply the Fourier transform we get
$$
\partial_t^2 \widehat{\phi}(t, \xi)+|\xi|^2 \widehat{\phi}(t, \xi)=\widehat{F}(t, \xi)
$$
now we fix $\xi$ the homogeneous version is
$$
\partial_t^2 \widehat{\phi}(t, \xi)+|\xi|^2 \widehat{\phi}(t, \xi)=0
$$
which has a basis of solutions as $u_{1}(t,\xi)=\sin(|\xi|t)$ and $u_{2}(t,\xi)=\cos(|\xi|t)$, now we want to find a particular solution, according to the variation of parameters, such particular solution has the form of
$$A(t,\xi)\sin(|\xi|t)+B(t,\xi)\cos(|\xi|t)$$
, the Wronskian $W$ is $u_{1}u_{2}'-u_{2}u_{1}'$, which is
$$W=-|\xi|$$
now the variation of parameters tells us that $$
A(t,\xi) = -\int \frac{1}{W} u_2(t,\xi) \widehat{F}(t, \xi) \mathrm{d} t, \quad B(t,\xi) = \int \frac{1}{W} u_1(t,\xi) \widehat{F}(t, \xi) \mathrm{d} t
$$
with a difference of a constant, we can rewrite this by using definite integral as
$$
A(t,\xi)=-\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{W} u_2(s,\xi) \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \mathrm{d} s, \quad B(t,\xi) = \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{W} u_1(s,\xi) \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \mathrm{d} s
$$
note that the $t$ is the upper bound of the integral domain,which can be regarded fixed with respect to $s$, hence we can put it in integral, hence $$A(t,\xi) \sin(|\xi|t)=-\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{W} u_2(s,\xi) \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \sin(|\xi|t) \mathrm{d} s =\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{|\xi|} \cos(|\xi|s) \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \sin(|\xi|t) \mathrm{d} s $$, we also get that $$B(t,\xi) \cos(|\xi|t)=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{W} u_1(s,\xi) \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \cos(|\xi|t) \mathrm{d} s =-\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{|\xi|} \cos(|\xi|t) \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \sin(|\xi|s) \mathrm{d} s $$
add it up and by using the trigonometric function difference formula we get $$
A(t,\xi) \sin(|\xi|t) + B(t,\xi) \cos(|\xi|t) = \int_0^t \frac{\sin ((t-s)|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \mathrm{d} s
$$
the above is a particular solution, combined with the general solution we get the general solution as
$$\widehat{\phi}(t, \xi)=c_{1}(\xi) \sin (|\xi| t)+c_{2}(\xi) \cos (|\xi| t)+\int_0^t \frac{\sin ((t-s)|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \mathrm{d} s$$
by setting $\widehat{\phi}(0, \xi)=\widehat{\phi_0(\xi)}$ we get
$$c_{2}( \xi)=\widehat{\phi_0(\xi)}$$
, note that
$$\frac{d\int_0^t \frac{\sin ((t-s)|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{\boldsymbol{F}}(s, \xi) \mathrm{d} s}{dt}=(\frac{\sin ((t-s)|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{\boldsymbol{F}}(s, \xi))|_{s=t}+\int_0^t \frac{d( \frac{\sin ((t-s)|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{\boldsymbol{F})}(s, \xi)}{dt}\mathrm{d} s$$
, when $t=0$, the derivative of the integral with respect to $t$ is $0$, now let $\partial_t \hat{\phi}|_{t=0}=\hat{\phi_{1}}(\xi)$, we get
$$c_{1}(\xi)|\xi|=\hat{\phi_{1}}(\xi)$$
, add it up we get
$$\widehat{\phi}(t, \xi) = \cos(t|\xi|) \widehat{\phi}_0(\xi) + \frac{\sin (t|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{\phi}_1(\xi) + \int_0^t \frac{\sin((t-s)|\xi|)}{|\xi|} \widehat{F}(s, \xi) \mathrm{d} s$$

This is my solution, please point out anywhere which could be wrong

I have fixed this @Winther

It looks correct to me now. It satisfied the PDE and it has the correct initial conditions.
